# Grouping of dataframe to find the count and sum on columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grouping

I have a dataframe like

```
       customer        fruit    price
0      cust1           mango     30
1      cust2           apple     45
2      cust1           banana    55
3      cust3           mango     22
4      cust4           banana    54
5      cust3           apple     55
6      cust2           apple     90
7      cust1           mango     45
8      cust3           banana    45
9      cust2           mango     23
10     cust4           mango     44
```

I need to get how much each customer spent on buying mango and on other fruits (i.e. not mango itself as a category) and count purchases by each customer, again, mango as its own category and other fruits in a separate column. Something like:

```
      customer   price spent_on_mango  spent_on_others
0      cust1          75                    55   
1      cust2          23                    135       
2      cust3          22                    100
3      cust4          44                    54
```

Comment: Please show how you exactly initialize your dataframe

Comment: from a csv i read that by     import panda as pd.    df = pd.read_csv('path')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you create a column to indicate whether or not the fruit is a mango and then include that in your `groupby`?

```
df['mango'] = df.fruit == 'mango'
df2 = df.groupby(['customer', 'mango']).sum().unstack()
df2.columns = ['not mango', 'mango']

>>> df2
          not mango  mango
customer                  
cust1            55     75
cust2           135     23
cust3           100     22
cust4            54     44
```

Comment: ,Thanks.But is there any to rename those False True to spent_on mango and spent_on others.or how will i get these in two diff columns.

Answer (score 2):

We could replace the elements in 'fruit' that are not 'mango' to 'others', then `groupby` the variables ('customer', 'fruit'), get the `sum` and `unstack`.

```
import pandas as pd
df1.loc[df1.fruit !='mango', 'fruit'] = 'others'
print(df1.groupby(['customer', 'fruit']).sum().unstack()) 
#         price       
#fruit    mango others
#customer             
#cust1       75     55
#cust2       23    135
#cust3       22    100
#cust4       44     54
```

Answer (score 2):

Another `pandas` approach:

```
df.fruit[df.fruit != 'mango'] = 'other_fruit'
pd.pivot_table(df, 'price', 'customer', 'fruit', np.sum)

fruit     mango  other_fruit
customer                    
cust1        75           55
cust2        23          135
cust3        22          100
cust4        44           54
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you can do this as a [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
In [11]: res = df.pivot_table("price", "customer", "fruit", fill_value=0)

In [12]: res
Out[12]:
fruit     apple  banana  mango
customer
cust1       0.0      55   37.5
cust2      67.5       0   23.0
cust3      55.0      45   22.0
cust4       0.0      54   44.0
```

Which may be good  enough, but you can create the desired "non-mango":

```
In [13]: mango = res.pop("mango")

In [14]: res.sum(axis=1).to_frame(name="not mango").join(mango)
Out[14]:
          not mango  mango
customer
cust1          55.0   37.5
cust2          67.5   23.0
cust3         100.0   22.0
cust4          54.0   44.0
```

*Generally if you see a stack/unstack you should instead try "pivot" :).*

Comment: ,great help and a new way

Answer (score 0):

Try grouping certain columns and then apply sum() like this:

```
print dframe.groupby(["customer","fruit"]).sum()
```

Like the command says itself, it groups the columns and adds up the values.

It returns a dataFrame with the information you need.

Comment: I have tried this before.by this i am getting sum for all fruits indivisually..But i want two extra columns to show up spent money on two groups one is on mango and other one as not on mango.